# Ubuntu 12.04 Dual monitor

Tags: monitor

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 with 3 Monitors. One monitor shows up but the other 2 do not. My card is 2 GTX480 Nvidia in sli mode. I have tried to run sudo nvidia-settings but nothing shows up.

Any thoughts would be welcome

Comment: Do you have your drivers ? nvidia-settings is part of the driver package.

Go to system settings then additional drivers.

Comment: What is the output of `xrandr -q` ?

Answer (score 1):

did you install the non free nvidia drivers or are you using the opensource drivers?  the non free drivers can be a pain with multiple monitors.  I have a 2nd display rotated 90 degrees and it gets to be painfull some times due to limitations in the drivers.

assuming you have installed non free and the config utility it should show in the system > administration menu. I am using the "classic" interface not sure on unity.

lsmod | grep nv  should return nvidia  for non free.

Comment: I did use nVidia non free drivers with Xinerama and 3 monitors and I was very satisfied. But that was no SLI mode.